# Which genres of African folk music uses high strung tuning on guitars?

Tags: guitar, alternative-tunings, genre, world-music, african

Several links (https://www.premierguitar.com/diy/exploring-nashville-tuning, for example) make a distinction between high-strung tuning (an octave higher EAD strings) and Nashville tuning (an octave higher EADG strings). Where this distinction is made, they say that high-strung tuning is used in certain genres of African folk music.

Which genres of African folk music use high-strung tuning on guitars?

Comment: All I'm seeing from some initial broad search is mention of a tuning among 1920s Zulu guitarists that was like standard guitar tuning except that the highest string is lowered to a D. It's probably true, as [this book](https://www.google.com/books/edition/South_African_Music/3IhJmobbZ4wC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=african%20guitar%20tuning&pg=PA138&printsec=frontcover) says, that there's a lot of variation (even if one zooms way in from "Africa" to a particular culture and time).